# Transmission tracker "Could not connect to tracker"

Tags: networking, transmission

I just upgraded to ubuntu 14.04 and updated transmission to 2.82

```
adrian@my-little-friend:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

adrian@my-little-friend:~$ transmission-gtk --version
transmission-gtk 2.82 (14160)
```

I noticed the all the torrents I'm currently downloading stopped and the transmission showed "Could not connect to tracker" while the internet connection is unchanged and I can browse internet and download normally.

I have tried re-installing, purging and re-adding the torrents but they bear no fruit.
Installed other torrent clients too (qtorrent, deluge, ktorrent) same results.

```
adrian@my-little-friend:~$ transmission-daemon -f
[02:01:09.738] Transmission 2.82 (14160) started (session.c:738)
[02:01:09.738] RPC Server Adding address to whitelist: 127.0.0.1 (rpc-server.c:828)
[02:01:09.738] RPC Server Serving RPC and Web requests on port 127.0.0.1:9091/transmission/ (rpc-server.c:1035)
[02:01:09.738] RPC Server Whitelist enabled (rpc-server.c:1039)
[02:01:09.738] RPC Server Password required (rpc-server.c:1042)
[02:01:09.738] DHT Generating new id (tr-dht.c:310)
[02:01:09.738] Using settings from "/home/adrian/.config/transmission-daemon" (daemon.c:526)
[02:01:09.738] Saved "/home/adrian/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json" (variant.c:1217)
[02:01:09.738] transmission-daemon requiring authentication (daemon.c:546)
[02:01:09.738] Port Forwarding (NAT-PMP) initnatpmp succeeded (0) (natpmp.c:73)
[02:01:09.738] Port Forwarding (NAT-PMP) sendpublicaddressrequest succeeded (2) (natpmp.c:73)
[02:01:11.738] Port Forwarding (UPnP) Found Internet Gateway Device "http://192.168.55.1:1900/ipc" (upnp.c:202)
[02:01:11.738] Port Forwarding (UPnP) Local Address is "192.168.55.100" (upnp.c:204)
[02:01:11.738] Port Forwarding (UPnP) Port forwarding through "http://192.168.55.1:1900/ipc", service "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1". (local address: 192.168.55.100:51422) (upnp.c:279)
[02:01:11.738] Port Forwarding (UPnP) Port forwarding successful! (upnp.c:282)
[02:01:11.738] Port Forwarding State changed from "Not forwarded" to "Forwarded" (port-forwarding.c:95)

adrian@my-little-friend:~$ sudo ufw status
[sudo] password for adrian: 
Status: inactive

adrian@my-little-friend:~/Downloads$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:9e:5f:77:12  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:44 Base address:0x8000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:7859 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7859 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1707198 (1.7 MB)  TX bytes:1707198 (1.7 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:64:5d:c3:da  
          inet addr:192.168.55.100  Bcast:192.168.55.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:895907 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:530457 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1311548594 (1.3 GB)  TX bytes:48451053 (48.4 MB)

adrian@my-little-friend:~/Downloads$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Homo Network"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 10:FE:ED:A5:48:44   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=14 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-36 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:3535   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: the output of `ifconfig` and `iwconfig` might be useful to add to your question.

Comment: @ElderGeek Just added them as requested.

Answer (score 1):

UPnP seems to be correctly forwarding the port 51422 to your ip address. You might try configuring your router port forwarding manually.

It's also possible the tracker you are using is down.  Can you ping it?

[image: trackerping]

Comment: I can't ping the sites but oddly enough I can access it via web browser

Comment: the trackers are often at a different IP address than the websites. You should login to the sites and ask about the trackers or check the trackers listed in your torrent files and see if you can ping them. or try adding a different tracker to your torrent files http://openbittorrent.com/ lists an open tracker and includes info on how to add a tracker to a torrent file.

Comment: I added various alternate trackers but they shows same results "Could not connect to tracker" on the other hand, another machine on the same network has no problem connecting to trackers and downloading from peers. Could be I'm missing some libraries for network routing/connections?

Comment: Look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/293356/how-to-open-a-particular-port-in-ubuntu and here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/406010/how-can-i-open-a-port-on-ubuntu?rq=1 I think you'll find these useful.

Comment: Do you still have this problem?